# Xamarin Forms: How to play Video using Plugin.MediaManager.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, video-player

I am trying to play a video using `Plugin.MediaManager.Forms` and I am referring to this [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-video-player-app/).

**Step 1:** Added `Plugin.MediaManager` and `Plugin.MediaManager.Forms`.

**Step 2:** XAML code - Added a `VideoView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VideoPlayerApp"  
             x:Class="VideoPlayerApp.MainPage"  
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Plugin.MediaManager.Forms;assembly=Plugin.MediaManager.Forms"  
             Title="Video Player">  

    <ContentPage.Content>  
        <StackLayout>  

            <Label Text="Xamarin Forms"  
                   FontSize="40"  
                   TextColor="Azure"/>  
            <Label Text="Video Player Application"  
                   FontSize="58"  
                   TextColor="BlueViolet"/>  
            <Button x:Name="PlayStopButtonText"  
                    Text="Play"   
                    Clicked="PlayStopButton"  
                    TextColor="BlueViolet"/>  
            <forms:VideoView HeightRequest="202"  
                             WidthRequest="202"/>  
        </StackLayout>  
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Step 3:** xaml.cs code

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private string videoUrl = "https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/e68c/690eebb1-797a-40ef-a841-c63dded4e68c/Cognitive-Services-Emotion_high.mp4";
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PlayStopButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (PlayStopButtonText.Text == "Play")
            {
                CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(videoUrl, MediaFileType.Video);

                PlayStopButtonText.Text = "Stop";
            }
            else if (PlayStopButtonText.Text == "Stop")
            {
                CrossMediaManager.Current.Stop();

                PlayStopButtonText.Text = "Play";
            }
        }
    }
```

But getting error on this step:

> Error  CS0103  The name 'MediaFileType' does not exist in the current context

**Step 4:** Also added `VideoViewRenderer.Init();`in `MainActivity.cs`, `AppDelegate.cs` and `MainPage.xaml.cs`. But getting following error for this initialization.

> The name 'VideoViewRenderer' does not exist in the current context

Am I missing something? I checked some other blogs but same error occuring. I have added a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18fQaLNl7HV_mq0gekAJWSDzjgqKPiR6g).

Android Options Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog seems out of date. Part of APIs and methods were obsoleted . You should check the newest docs from https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager#usage .

use the following code instead of `VideoViewRenderer.Init()` ;

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();
```

And just need to call the method

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(videoUrl);
```

And I checked your demo . You need to update the version of Xamarin.Forms to 4.2.x both in share project and specific platforms(Android and iOS) .Which will match to the version of the plugin.

Don't forget to set the Dex complier to **d8** .

Right click your Android project -> Property-> Android Options.

[image]

Comment: No Dex compiler option in android property?

Comment: Right click the android project(not share project).

Comment: I checked on the android project. No Dex compiler option found.

Comment: Update your IDE to the newest version .

Comment: Currect Version: VS 2017, 15.9.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200153/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-lucas-zhang-msft).

Comment: Update it to VS 2019(16.3.x)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to load the below URL video, unfortunately it is not loading, can you please have a look. https://player.vimeo.com/video/361089481